# Getting value from one row and take its corresponding value from another column and passing it again into same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. I queried the first table by ID and got A12 which I need to put in the table below.
But table below with A12 is like a route, that is A12 is associated with B12 and B12 is associated with A14 which makes it indirectly associated with A12 and it keeps going until all connections to A12 are found.

So from this logic, I should get unique values consisting of A12, B12, B13, B22, A14, B20, B21, A15, B36 and use that.

Is there a way to do that in SQL please? I kept trying for days but came up empty.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

| RECEIVED | SENT |
| --- | --- |
| A12 | B12 |
| A12 | B13 |
| A12 | B22 |
| B12 | A14 |
| C13 | C16 |
| A14 | B20 |
| B13 | B21 |
| B20 | A15 |
| B36 | A12 |

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear.

Comment: You do need to [edit] your question to tag the *correct* RDBMS though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about mysql (if it lets you perform loops and declare variables and temporary tables in the same way as MSSQL).. however, if I've understood your question correctly the following works in MSSQL (I've called the table TestTable)

---

```
DECLARE @ResultsTable table (Outputvalue char(3))
DECLARE @ProcessedResultsTable  table (Outputvalue char(3))



DECLARE @Searchvalue char(3) ='A12'

INSERT INTO @ResultsTable (Outputvalue) SELECT @Searchvalue


WHILE 

(
SELECT COUNT(Testtable.[sent]) FROM Testtable 
INNER JOIN @ResultsTable T ON T.Outputvalue = Testtable.[received]
WHERE Testtable.[sent] NOT IN (Select P.Outputvalue FROM @ResultsTable P)
)>0

OR

(SELECT COUNT(Testtable.[received]) FROM Testtable 
INNER JOIN @ResultsTable T ON T.Outputvalue = Testtable.[sent]
WHERE Testtable.[received] NOT IN (Select P.Outputvalue FROM @ResultsTable P)
)>0



BEGIN



INSERT INTO @ResultsTable(Outputvalue) SELECT Testtable.[sent] FROM Testtable 
INNER JOIN @ResultsTable T ON T.Outputvalue = Testtable.[received]
WHERE Testtable.[sent] NOT IN (Select P.Outputvalue FROM @ResultsTable P)



INSERT INTO @ResultsTable(Outputvalue) SELECT Testtable.[received] FROM Testtable 
INNER JOIN @ResultsTable T ON T.Outputvalue = Testtable.[sent]
WHERE Testtable.[received] NOT IN (Select P.Outputvalue FROM @ResultsTable P)



END

SELECT * FROM @ResultsTable
```

---

Hope this helps

Kind Regards

Kev

Comment: thank you so much!!! I wanted to ask if you knew of something similar in postgresql? I am quite new to SQL and still trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: You're welcome, hope it turns out to be useful.  I don't know Postgresql but I know that it is possible to do loops.  Should just be a case of converting the above to the relevant postgress syntax.  Good look.